# Wordpress get template part with if statement shows both templates

Tags: wordpress

I'm using ACF and I would like to display posts in a different way according to the category. Here is my single :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if(!function_exists('get_field')) return; ?>

<main class="main_flex">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        if ( in_category('dossiers') ) { get_template_part( 'single_dossier' );
        } else { get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
        } ?>
    <article>
    <!-- content here -->
    </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And in a file I named single_dossier.php, I wrote this :

```
<?php if(!function_exists('get_field')) return; ?>

<article>
    <!-- different content here -->
</article>
```

When I go to an article with the category "dossiers", it loads both the contents. Anyone could tell me what I did wrong and how to correct it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have 2 posts with same id/slug (Depending on your permalink structure).

For check this use this code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if(!function_exists('get_field')) return; ?>

<main class="main_flex">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $x = 0; ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $x++;
        echo '{{' . $x . ':' . $post->ID . '}}';
        if ( in_category('dossiers') ) { get_template_part( 'single_dossier' );
        } else { get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
        } ?>
    <article>
    <!-- content here -->
    </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And let see if you get in output {{1:someID}} & {{2:someAnotherID}}.

Or use the following code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if(!function_exists('get_field')) return; ?>

<main class="main_flex">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php
        the_post();
        if ( in_category('dossiers') ) { get_template_part( 'single_dossier' );
        } else { get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
        } ?>
    <article>
    <!-- content here -->
    </article>
    <?php endif; ?>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi! I did what you suggested, as a result I have : {{2:1815}} What does it mean?

Comment: @Soph87 And What is the first? {{1:???}}. Its mean My guess was right :) You have 2 posts with same Id or slug link.

Comment: That's what's weird, there isn't a {{1:XXXX}}. Any idea what to do......?

Comment: @Soph87
I added to the answer more code option without using the loop of WordPress.

It's not recommended as is but in post page its will some ok.

Just to make sure, you talk about `get_template_part` not about `<article>
    <!-- content here -->
    </article>` correct?

Comment: It's still not working. You can see the result  [here](http://92.222.93.153/index.php/2017/05/19/cannes-2017). I'm not sure I understand your question... Maybe you need to see more code to understand? I can make a gist if you like. Thanks for trying to help me by the way! :)

Comment: @Soph87 I took a look at the site but it does not help so much.
In your code, you have `<article>
    <!-- content here -->
    </article>` *after* the if else statmante so I just  make sure its not the part of article.
And yes, full code of single.php will be more helpful.

Comment: Here you [go](https://gist.github.com/Soph87/0b3b21c1a0f4ff74c8014377bdb58825). Hope this helps ><'

Comment: @Soph87 That's what I feared before.
You simply type the single after the if and else...

There is the [fixed code](https://gist.github.com/Webstorm-IL/476803fa5f5e1b4ebe8bf0227a4b3f68)

I add file content-single.php, it's will be under "template-parts" subdir.

Comment: It works, thank you so much!! :D I followed a tutorial, maybe I shouldn't have done that..... Anyway, thanks again!!